# Field changed type from RECORD to STRING

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am pushing some data from the last 10 days into BigQuery. One of my field variables is a repeated record, X, with two int fields Y and Z. For two of the 10 days, I am getting an error that Field X has changed type from RECORD to STRING (this didn't happen for the 8 other days). I am printing out these types though and they remain lists. I even made sure that in the case that X is an empty list, I changed it to {Y: None, Z: None}. Why is it saying that the field changed types and how can I fix this?

Comment: Please add more context. Screenshots? Exact error message? Where are you getting this message?